# Making a new branch and setting its upstream in one Git command

Tags: git

My usual workflow for making a new branch is

```
git checkout -b My-New-Branch
```

and then after some local commits

```
git push --set-upstream origin My-New-Branch
```

Looking at the documentation for [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) it looks like I should be able to use `--track` to set the new upstream branch as I make the local branch, but I cannot seem to make it work: these all fail with the error given.

```
git checkout --track origin/My-New-Branch
git checkout -b My-New-Branch --track origin/My-New-Branch
git checkout -b My-New-Branch --track origin My-New-Branch
git checkout -b --track origin My-New-Branch
```

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'My-New-Branch' at the
>   same time.
>   Did you intend to checkout 'My-New-Branch' which can not
>   be resolved as commit?

Is it possible to set the upstream as I create a new branch in Git?

Comment: It definitely requires at least two steps, because all the one-step processes require that the remote-tracking branch actually exist at the time you create the new local branch, and by definition, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an alias to do that:

```
git config --global alias.co-push '!f() { git checkout -b $1; git push --set-upstream origin $1; }; f'
```

This will allow you to do `git co-push My-New-Branch`, which will execute both commands you have been executing separate before. If you need to push to different remotes, you can exchange "origin" with "$2" in the definition and then do `git co-push My-New-Branch origin`.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Am I right in thinking that your implicit answer is that it cannot be done without aliasing two commands together?

Comment: At least I do not know of another way.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushautoSetupRemote