# Create new git branch and track or set upstream the new branch

Tags: git, github

I.e.: what's the equivalent of these:

```
git checkout -b my_new_local_branch # create a new local branch
git push --set-upstream origin my_new_local_branch # track / set upstream the new local branch to remote repo
```

but with one command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a new branch and setting its upstream in one Git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245953/making-a-new-branch-and-setting-its-upstream-in-one-git-command)

Comment: @nofinator That answer is wrong.

Comment: @nofinator no it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable via the [`push.autoSetupRemote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushautoSetupRemote) setting. The `--set-upstream` command will be given for you when you push. You will still need two commands, because making a branch and pushing it are very different things (and you wouldn't want them to be the same thing).